# Getting register error :Account missing when integrating GCM for pushwoosh in android

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am successfully integrating pushwoosh in my android application.I am using GCM.here is my code:

```
oncreate:
    PushManager pushManager = new PushManager(this,
                App_id, Sender_id);
        pushManager.onStartup(savedInstanceState, this);
        checkMessage(getIntent());


   @Override
        protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            super.onNewIntent(intent);
            setIntent(intent);

            checkMessage(intent);

            setIntent(new Intent());
        }

        private void checkMessage(Intent intent)
        {
            if (null != intent)
            {
                if (intent.hasExtra(PushManager.PUSH_RECEIVE_EVENT))
                {
                    showMessage("push message is " + intent.getExtras().getString(PushManager.PUSH_RECEIVE_EVENT));
                }
                else if (intent.hasExtra(PushManager.REGISTER_EVENT))
                {
                    showMessage("register");
                }
                else if (intent.hasExtra(PushManager.UNREGISTER_EVENT))
                {
                    showMessage("unregister");
                }
                else if (intent.hasExtra(PushManager.REGISTER_ERROR_EVENT))
                {
                    showMessage("register error");
                }
                else if (intent.hasExtra(PushManager.UNREGISTER_ERROR_EVENT))
                {
                    showMessage("unregister error");
                }
            }
        }

        private void showMessage(String message)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

But when i am running my app its showing register error.I can not find what's the problem?In logcat it shows Messaging registration error:Account Missing.Please Help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Account Missing error occurred when there is no Google account on the phone. Here is the official explanation from GCM page.

> There is no Google account on the phone. The Android application
>   should ask the user to open the account manager and add a Google
>   account. Fix on the device side.

For more information check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html#handling_reg).

Answer (score 3):

If you have "account missing" error you need to configure your Google Account on the device.
Open the account manager and add a Google account there.
Also make sure you can to login to the Android Marketplace from the device.

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing the problem, but as far I understood that the appid and senderId is wrong here, try with the new one.